# RecyclerView onitemClickListener in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am new on kotlin .Getting error on click listner on line `holder.initilise(chapterlist.get(position),clickListener)`
Error shows on word clickListener . Kindly help me to resolve my issue. i want to click on one view and transfer on another recyclerView. These list shows chapters i want to go on topics list and every chapter has its own `topics.holder.initilise(chapterlist.get(position),clickListener)` is commented in the code and it just shows the list which i extract from backend

Code :

```
import android.content.Context
import android.view.Display
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class CustomeAdapter(val ctx: Context, var clickListener: Int, var chapterlist:ArrayList<Model>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>() {


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val user : Model = chapterlist[position]
       holder?.textViewName?.text=user.name
        holder?.textViewChapter?.text=user.desc


  //   holder.initilise(chapterlist.get(position),clickListener) //(getting error on clickListener)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context).inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return chapterlist.size
         }

}

class ViewHolder(itemView: View) :RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

    val textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView) as TextView
    val textViewChapter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2) as TextView

    fun initilise(list: Model, action:OnChapterClick){
        textViewName.text=list.name
        textViewChapter.text=list.desc

        itemView.setOnClickListener{
            action.onItemClick(list,adapterPosition)
        }

    }
}

interface OnChapterClick {
    fun onItemClick(list: Model,position: Int )

}
```

Comment: How do you initialize your `CustomeAdapter`? `clickListener` should be type of `OnChapterClick`

Comment: sir after this i got an error on main kotlin file on R.layout.row
val adapter=CustomeAdapter(applicationContext,R.layout.row,chapterlist) recycleView.adapter=adapter

Comment: Can you add your main kotlin file?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1UCfnh4y6GMjGy77MWGL1uFVLOl_GkVPg
kindly click on link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps:

**Step - 1:** You have to **implements** `OnChapterClick` in your `MainActivity2`

```
class MainActivity2: AppCompatActivity, OnChapterClick {
    ....

    override fun onItemClick(list: Model, position: Int ) {

        //Implement your logic here
    } 
}
```

**Step - 2:** Change your `CustomeAdapter`'s constructor to accept `OnChapterClick` instead of `int`

```
class CustomeAdapter(val ctx: Context, var clickListener: OnChapterClick, var chapterlist:ArrayList<Model>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>() {

    ....
}
```

**Step - 3:** Initialize the adapter with `this` instead of `R.layout.row` like below:

```
val adapter = CustomeAdapter(applicationContext, this@MainActivity2, chapterlist)
```

Comment: @account, Check my answer . Follow step -2 and step -3 as you already did step - 1

Comment: Try with `this@MainActivity2`

Answer (score 0):

Your clickListener is defined to be an `Int`:

```
var clickListener: Int
```

That's probably wrong, since integers can't listen to clicks.  It should probably be:

```
var clickListener: OnChapterClick
```

Comment: Sir now i got an error in main kotlin file

 val adapter=CustomeAdapter(applicationContext,R.layout.row,chapterlist)
                   recycleView.adapter=adapter

Comment: on R.layout.row

Comment: `R.layout.row` isn't an `OnChapterClick`, and you're trying to pass it as one.  You need to make the types match the function signature.

Comment: sir can u explain it more?please